# How can I disable thread messages in debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the VSCode C/C++ extension to debug Rust applications. My launch configuration is:

```
{
  "name": "Debug",
  "type": "cppvsdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/hello_world.exe",
  "args": [],
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "environment": [],
  "logging": {
    "moduleLoad": false,
    "engineLogging": false,
    "exceptions": true,
    "programOutput": true
  }
}
```

When using this, I get the following output:

```
The thread 23128 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Hello, world!
The thread 19808 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 3232 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[19188] mao.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I would like to hide the messages regarding threads since they are noisy and irrelevant to my work.

How can I disable these?